# create odoo menu (python code)

Tags: python, odoo

I want to create a simple menu in odoo, but when i run the code below is gives the error: External ID not found in the system etc..

```
<menuitem name ="Technische informatie" id="menu_technical_information_root" sequence="50"/>
<menuitem action="action_technical_information" id="menu_action_technical_information"
parent="menu_technical_information_root" sequence="20"/>
```

Comment: Errors are important. Don't write "etc." instead of showing us the whole text.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error here.

Answer (score 0):

if you create action menu then must be define a action of the records.

this Example code helping you.

```
<menuitem name ="Technische informatie" id="menu_technical_information_root" sequence="50"/>

<record id="action_technical_information" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Your Orders</field>
    <field name="res_model">your.model</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="lunch_order_view_search"/>
    <field name="context"></field>
    <field name="help" type="html"></field>
</record>
<menuitem action="action_technical_information" id="menu_action_technical_information" parent="menu_technical_information_root" sequence="20"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to get  External id error, If your action view record id "action_technical_information" is not equal to menuitem action name "menuitem action="action_technical_information" then you get the External ID not found in the system

These are the steps for creating simple menu:

view:

```
<record id="technical_information_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">form_name</field>
        <field name="model">model.name</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="form_name">
                <group col="8" colspan="8">
                    <field name="from_date"/>                    
                    <field name="to_date"/>
                    <newline/> 
                </group>
           </form>
        </record>
```

Action:

```
<record id="action_technical_information" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">name</field>
            <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="technical_information_view"/>
            <field name="target">new</field>
            <field name="help">name</field>
        </record>
```

Menu Items:

```
<menuitem name ="Technische informatie" id="menu_technical_information_root" sequence="50"/>

  <menuitem action="action_technical_information" id="menu_technical_information_root"
            parent="menu_technical_information_root" sequence="20"/>
```